# For an error correction code $C$, does $\langle\psi| E|\phi\rangle/\langle\psi|\phi\rangle$ being constant imply the code has distance $2$?

Tags: error-correction

Let $ C $ be a code. Let $ |\psi\rangle $ and $ |\phi\rangle $ be non-orthogonal codewords. Suppose that for every weight $ 1 $ Pauli $ E $ it is the case that the value
$$
\frac{\langle \psi | E| \phi\rangle}{\langle \psi | \phi\rangle}
$$
is independent of $ |\psi\rangle $ and $ |\phi\rangle $. Does that imply that the code $ C $ has distance $ 2 $?

Update: It appears that this condition implies $ d \geq 2 $, although not necessarily $ d=2 $, as noted in the answer below.

Comment: Please do not edit questions in ways that alter their meaning after answers have been posted. Instead, feel free to post new questions.

Comment: @AdamZalcman You are right! I just put the stuff about $ d \geq 2 $ in an update instead, I think I found this alternative formulation of distance in a textbook by Gottesman I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Any code of distance $d>2$ is a counterexample since in any such code a single-qubit Pauli error sends every codeword to a subspace orthogonal to the code subspace, so $\langle\psi|E|\phi\rangle=0$ for all codewords $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ and all non-identity single-qubit Pauli errors $E$.

If $C$ is a distance $d>2$ stabilizer code with stabilizer group $\mathcal{S}$ we can show this more rigorously as follows. Since $E$ has unit weight there exists $A\in\mathcal{S}$ which anti-commutes with it, so
$$
\langle\psi|E|\phi\rangle=\langle\psi|EA|\phi\rangle=-\langle\psi|AE|\phi\rangle=-\langle\psi|E|\phi\rangle\tag1
$$
and $\langle\psi|E|\phi\rangle=0$.